# Search for a specific pattern and remove/trim suffix if found in an array of strings

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to remove the ".com" suffix from the domain name field which is an array of strings separated by a pipe(|)

The data looks like below-

```
ID          domain
1        ab23c45 | xyz167a.com | d1ef76om.com |rx08bj23
2        omg23hy5 | xyz167a | ab23c45.com | jhy2ft3.com
```

The result should look like-

```
ID          domain
1        ab23c45 | xyz167a | d1ef76om |rx08bj23
2        omg23hy5 | xyz167a | ab23c45 | jhy2ft3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT id,  
  (
    SELECT STRING_AGG(TRIM(REPLACE(TRIM(domain), IFNULL(NET.PUBLIC_SUFFIX(TRIM(domain)), ''), ''), '.'), ' | ') 
    FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(domain, '|')) domain
  ) domain
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

if to apply to sample data from your question - output is

```
Row id  domain   
1   1   ab23c45 | xyz167a | d1ef76om | rx08bj23  
2   2   omg23hy5 | xyz167a | ab23c45 | jhy2ft3
```

Note: above code handles any suffix - not just '.com'

Comment: Looks better, I removed my answer

Comment: above solution supports whatever is considered public suffix  - as it is treated by `NET.PUBLIC_SUFFIX` built-in function. looks like in your case above needs to be adjusted to handle any suffix - do you still want the answer for this or you can start off of this answer by yourself? let me know

Comment: Would appreciate an answer. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: @user11035754 - btw. I just tested with `.network` and it does work as expected - i suggest you to double check your data!!! so I don't see need in further actions on my side :o)

Comment: I have many variations to the suffix in my original data. And it is probably why it doesn't work for all cases